# How do I Recover Unsaved Files in Nebeans After Crash?

Tags: java, netbeans, crash, restore

While working on a Java file in (Apache) Netbeans 14, my computer went off due to a power outage. Unfortunately, I had made a long string of edits without saving them. Is there a way to recover the edits? I have tried file history but it's showing only copies of the file that were saved.

Comment: Not sure how Netbeans works internally on that score but you can use `grep` in Unix and `find` in Windows to look for identifying strings. Get yourself a UPS - power outages are more likely than not going to increase ;) Netbeans should probably have an auto-save option I would have thought

Answer (score 0):

Your changes are lost. There's an autosave plugin for the next time: https://plugins.netbeans.apache.org/catalogue/?id=22

Comment: To be clear, the code you link to is not a plugin since it's been incorporated into NetBeans. See **Tools > Options > Editor > Autosave**.